# Iterate Each Item in List as Sequential based on its Property Count

Tags: c#, list, sequence

I have a list of an object. I want to iterate each of it based on sequential order of each item's `Repeat` property.

**List:**

```
var files = new List<SDetail>(); 
files.Add(new SDetail { FileName = "file1", Sec = 40, Repeat = 39 });
files.Add(new SDetail { FileName = "file2", Sec = 10, Repeat = 24 });
files.Add(new SDetail { FileName = "file3", Sec = 150, Repeat = 2 });
```

I have done the list population based on the `Repeat` property.

Here is the snippet I tried.

```
if(files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in files)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < item.Repeat;)
                {
                    checkItem.Add(item.FileName);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(checkItem.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in checkItem)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

I get output for the above snippet like file1 (39 times), file2 (24 times), file3(2 times).

The output should be like this (sequential list item):

file1
file2
file3
file1
file2
file3
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file2
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1
file1

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Nice, what is your problem?

Comment: I couldn't achieve the output I mentioned above. Rather I get like file1 (39 times), file2(24 times), file3(2 times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So answer to your code is that you should iterate over whole `files` collection until there is any `Repeat` left.

```
while(files.Any(f => f.Repeat > 0))
{
    foreach(var f in files)
    {
        if(f.Repeat > 0)
        {
            checkItem.Add(f.FileName);
            f.Repeat--;
        }
    }
}

if(checkItem.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in checkItem)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Of course this is valid unless you are forbidden to change `SDetail` objects.

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how your iterations work. Since the order of your output list is important, the order of iterations is important too!

What I've added is a counter, `iterationCounter`. For every iteration, we will check all items in your list, take the ones who still need to be repeated, take their `FileName` property, and add it to the list we are building. (and then we start another iteration).
The iterations only stop when no more items are being added.

1. On the first loop, `iterationCounter = 1` and we must get all `FileName` properties where `Repeat >= 1`
2. On the second loop, `iterationCounter = 2` and we must get all `FileName` properties where `Repeat >= 2`
3. On the third loop, `iterationCounter = 3` and we must get all `FileName` properties where `Repeat >= 3`

I think you can see that every line constantly uses a 1, a 2 or a 3. Therefore, the logic can be constructect around this increasing `iterationCounter`.

```
public static List<String> MakeMyList(List<File> myListOfFiles)
{
    List<String> outputlist = new List<string>();
    int iterationCounter = 0;
    bool thereWereNamesAdded = true;

    while(thereWereNamesAdded)
    {
        //Increment the counter
        iterationCounter++; 

        //Find the names that still need to be added in this iteration
        List<String> theFileNames = myListOfFiles.Where(x => x.Repeat >= iterationCounter)
                                                 .Select(x => x.FileName)
                                                 .ToList();

        //Add the found names to the loop
        outputlist.AddRange(theFileNames);

        //If no file names were added in this loop,
        //set the boolean to false and exit the iteration
        thereWereNamesAdded = theFileNames.Any();
    }

    return outputlist;
}
```